# Show posts from two or more custom taxonomy terms

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, terms

I want to show posts which are filed 2 or more custom  taxonomy terms. For example, I want to show the posts from custom post type "Classified" and filed under Books *and* House terms.

The code below show posts which are marked in *either* of the terms. I want only the posts marked in *both* the terms:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,  // Number of posts per page
    'post_type' => 'classifieds',   // Custom Post Type like Movies
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'classifieds_tags',   //Custom Taxonomy Name like Genre
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(
                'books',    //Tags or Categories like Drama or Comedy
                'houses'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine two tax queries with and `AND` relation:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,  // Number of posts per page
    'post_type' => 'classifieds',   // Custom Post Type like Movies
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND'
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'classifieds_tags',   //Custom Taxonomy Name like Genre
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(
                'books' //Tags or Categories like Drama or Comedy
            )
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'classifieds_tags',   //Custom Taxonomy Name like Genre
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array(
                'houses'
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `relation`argument :

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,  // Number of posts per page
    'post_type' => 'classifieds',   // Custom Post Type like Movies
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'classifieds_tags',   //Custom Taxonomy Name like Genre
            'field' => 'slug',
            'relation' => 'AND',
            'terms' => array(
                'books',    //Tags or Categories like Drama or Comedy
                'houses'
            )
        )
    )
);
```